# To what extent does a successful GWT developer need to be a fully fledged 'web developer'?

Tags: gwt, extjs

- By 'web developer' I mean a software developer having a sound
  understanding of web fundamentals (HTTP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript and
  Ajax).
- By 'successful GWT developer' I mean someone who can produce
  high quality and polished looking GWT apps in timely fashion.

My department is gearing-up for a project that will require the development of a number of single screen RIA web apps. These will front enterprise server components implemented in Java. Our UI prototype was developed using [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) and was successful (in terms of speed of development and producing a professional, polished looking UI that integartes well with a service oriented API implemented using [Spring-MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html) + [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)). However, in gearing-up to develop the actual product we have realised that our department's skills profile isn't ideal for ExtJS. We are strong on Java but relatively weak on web developers. The development of the UI prototype demonstrated that you really need fully feldged web developers to get to grips with ExtJS, since they will spend a significant amount of time grappling with CSS and JavaScript issues. As a result, the question has arisen as to whether we might be better off going with GWT (combined with a library that offers a level of polish comparable to ExtJS, such as [SmartGWT](http://www.smartclient.com/product/smartgwt.jsp)). Obviously this assumes that GWT is significantly less demanding in terms of web development skills. To what extent would GWT + SmartGWT allow our Java developers to crank out high quality RIAs without them having to acquire anything more than a basic appreciation of the web fundamentals listed above?

If we decide to explore GWT further we'll do another prototype, but in the mean time it would be very interesting to hear the opinions of experienced GWT developers.

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that you can get away with a lot without advanced web skills, but the end result is a pretty bland looking app, but even worse, you'll find yourself struggling to achieve all the dynamic effects you want.

As an example, my app has a DataGrid on the main tab.  That could be done easily enough using pure GWT.  But then I wanted to put a checkbox under the DataGrid widget that the user could use to select "single line mode", in which the rows are one line each -- any data in cells that would have word-wrapped just disappears at the edge of the cell.  Hit the checkbox, and the rows collapse to one line each, then hit it again, and the row heights expand to whatever size is needed to display all the data in the cells.  There isn't a method for that.  What you have to do is adjust the row style of the DataGrid to add or remove the CSS element "white-space:nowrap;".  So you add a ValueChangeHandler to a CheckBox widget (GWT skills) that modifies a CSS style of the DataGrid widget (web skills).

Without web skills, you'll find yourself hitting walls in trying to achieve the look-and-feel (and even dynamic behaviour) you want.  Having said that, you can find these sorts of answers easily enough on the web.  The key thing to remember is that just because GWT doesn't seem to have a method for something, that maybe it's really a web issue, not a GWT issue, and that you have to remember to think outside of the GWT box to solve your problem (instead of throwing up your hands, blaming GWT for lacking a feature, and hoping something like SmartGWT will solve all your problems).

The fact that every GWT widget has a plethora of methods for setting, adding, and removing styles, and the very rich integration via ClientBundles and UiBinder and the like, means that this was always the intent.

Answer (score 2):

GWT is a very capable framework and can be used to produce great results such as [Pictarine](http://www.pictarine.com/), but as the developers of Pictarine [indicate](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2011/09/pictarine-pictures-in-cloud.html):

> Another thing that was not obvious to us when we started with GWT was that a java developer needs an intimate knowledge of HTML/CSS if he/she wants to go beyond the basic user interface provided by the GWT widgets.

I'm not quoting this to discourage anyone. Basic interfaces are indeed within reach with GWT without much HTML/CSS knowledge. GWT, however, leans on web languages and so in a non-trivial application familiarity with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS will come handy. Personally, using GWT has been continuously deepening my JS/HTML/CSS skills as I've been searching for ways to enhance my GWT projects, which in the end has been very rewarding.